# Can a test / updated helm chart NOTES.txt file be tested without rebuilding the chart?

Tags: testing, kubernetes-helm

I am looking to test a change in a Helm chart NOTES.txt file and intended to run a helm install with the `--dry-run` option, but I can not see how to specify an updated NOTES.txt file on my local file system (whether as part of a real or dry run install). I would like to validate changes to my NOTES.txt file but should there be multiple changes I don't want to have to make changes, commit, re-build, etc ... each time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the updated file. The contents of the `templates/NOTES.txt` including any changes made will be displayed at the bottom of the printout when you run the `helm install` command with `--dry-run`

The [helm docs](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/) also mention using the `--debug` flag:

> When you want to test the template rendering, but not actually install anything, you can use `helm install ./mychart --debug --dry-run`. This will send the chart to the Tiller server, which will render the templates. But instead of installing the chart, it will return the rendered template to you so you can see the output

Comment: Thanks @quertysmack.

I was aware that I could use `--debug` and  `--dry-run`, but my question was if (or how could I) specify a modified `NOTES.txt` at install time without having to initiate new builds each time I made an update to the file. I have come to the conclusion that this is not possible.